# Angular 2+ Retaining Scope and Detecting (transcluded/template) Content Passed to Child Component

Tags: angular

I need to pass HTML content (or `ng-template`?) to have it rendered within a child component. Sometimes content will *not* be passed, and the child component needs to know weather or not this is the case (it will have default content if nothing is passed). Also, I would like the (transcluded?) content to have the same scope as the parent component from which it was passed, or some way to access this scope.

I know how to accomplish passing the HTML with transclusion (Or maybe pass the template HTML with an input?), but not sure how to determine from the child *if* content is passed with transclusion. But the scoping is probably the major issue here.

I'm pretty sure I've seen how to pass `ng-template` as a parameter/input, but I could not find an example.

What is the standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you already know how to pass a template to the child you can use the following method to pass data. this can be a boolean or an object containing more variables if you need.

In the parent view

```html
<app-sub-component [setData]="someData"></app-sub-component>
```

In the child component

```js
 @Input()
 set setData(data: any) {
    this.data = data;
}
```